# Angular 15 downloading file from aws s3 url giving CORS Error

Tags: javascript, angular, amazon-s3, cors

I have made downloading files from aws s3 url by using javascript. It worked on my previous work on vue2 project. And I am cloning this function to Angular 15 project. But it gives CORS error when call api with httpclient GET method.

I have also tried fetch api, but still giving me same CORS error. But it worked on chrome browser opening with unsafe mode.

The differenece with the working vue2 project I found was, when I download file from angular 15 project  then it doesnt show Reqeust Headers on conosle window in Network tab.

And I set aws s3 cors config with belows.

**AWS CORS config**

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET",
            "HEAD"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": [
            "Content-Range",
            "Content-Length",
            "ETag"
        ],
        "MaxAgeSeconds": 3000
    }
]
```

**Angaulr script**

```
export class DownloadControllerService {
  constructor(
    private httpClient: HttpClient
  ) {}

  getBlobFile(url: string): Observable<Blob> {
    return this.httpClient.get<any>(url, {
      responseType: 'blob' as 'json',
    });
  }
}
```

And this is the Headers image from chrome console window.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fxyjl.png)

Any help will be great on this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You should also allows `OPTIONS` http method so preflight request could be made.

Comment: @Ioicb You mean on AWS CORS config?

Comment: If you mean that `OPTIONS` should be listed as an allowed method in the CORS config for preflight to succeed, you're mistaken. See [this instance of Jake Archibald's CORS playground](https://jakearchibald.com/2021/cors/playground/?prefillForm=1&requestMethod=POST&requestUseCORS=1&preflightStatus=204&preflightAllowOrigin=https%3A%2F%2Fjakearchibald.com&preflightAllowCredentials=&preflightAllowMethods=&preflightAllowHeaders=x-my-custom-header&responseStatus=200&responseAllowOrigin=https%3A%2F%2Fjakearchibald.com&requestHeaderName=x-my-custom-header&requestHeaderValue=foo).